# Mssql union two tables based on column value

Tags: sql, union

I have to tabels (tab_a and tab_b) both carrying customers data. The two tables have some records in common, or better, customers in common. The problem is they are identified by different customer's code and the names of the same customer may vary from one table to the other. The only common key they have is the VAT number.
What i need is a recordset with the customers from both tables but without dupicates.

I tried a regular UNION but the problem is that if the name of the customers is written slightly different from one tabel to the other i get a duplicate.

I short I need the result of

```
SELECT t1.vatnumber FROM tab_a AS t1 UNION t2.vatnumber FROM tab_b AS t2
```

But with the adition of the name of the cusotmers and his custumer code (taken from tab_a or if not present in tab_a from tab_b)

Any help is truly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: what db are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not going to get what you want readily with `distinct`.  A better approach might be `union all` with aggregation.  The following returns what you want -- but without precedence.  That is, if a name or code exists in both tables, then an arbitrary one is returned:

```
select vatnumber, max(name) as name, max(code) as code
from ((select a.vatnumber, a.name, a.code
       from tab_a
      ) union all
      (select b.vatnumber, b.name, b.code
       from tab_b
      )
     ) ab
group by vatnumber;
```

If you want precedence, then it is a bit more cumbersome.  Here is one method:

```
select vatnumber,
       coalesce(max(case when which = 'a' then name end), max(name)) as name,
       coalesce(max(case when which = 'a' then code end), max(code)) as code
from ((select a.vatnumber, a.name, a.code, 'a' as which
       from tab_a
      ) union all
      (select b.vatnumber, b.name, b.code, 'b' as which
       from tab_b
      )
     ) ab
group by vatnumber;
```

Comment: Absolutely fabulous! Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use UNION, it is simpler with FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT 
ISNULL(a.vatnumber, b.vatnumber) vatnumber, 
ISNULL(a.name, b.name) name,
...
FROM tab_a a FULL JOIN tab_b b ON a.vatnumber = b.vatnumber
```

Syntax will depend on DB that you are using. e.g. This example should be ok for MSSQL.